# How to add View to Gallery?

Tags: android, view, gallery, addition

I have multiple ListViews and would like to add those to Gallery.

I tried with addView but it is not supported since Gallery view is an AdapterView.

Can someone let me know how to go about it?

Regards

Sunil

Answer (score 1):

> I have multiple ListViews and would
>   like to add those to Gallery.

That is unlikely to work. Either the `Gallery` or the `ListView` scrolling probably will not function.

> I tried with addView but it is not
>   supported since Gallery view is an
>   AdapterView.

Correct.

> Can someone let me know how to go
>   about it?

You will need to create an `Adapter` containing your `ListViews`, and hand that `Adapter` to your `Gallery`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you let me know what shall I do for making the Gallery view move to the next View only. Currently the Gallery moves according to the swipe force. But I will like to move to the next view only. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

An example on how to use the Gallery class together with an Adapter can be found [here](http://www.anddev.org/a_androidwidgetgallery_-_example-t332.html). The adapter in this example provides images. You could provide your ListViews

Comment: -1. This answer is irresponsible and misleading. Adding a Listview to a gallery is quite different from adding a ImageView, which is why sunil has trouble implementing it.